# What is the best way to check if an Eloquent query returns no answer?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 4. Say I have an Eloquent model (Patient) and I want to get a patient with the name Bob, I would do this:

```
$patient = Patient::where('name', '=', 'Bob');
```

What is the best way to check to see if $patient is a valid record?

Comment: You can do `if(!$patient->isEmpty())`.

Comment: I may be wrong but doesn't `isEmpty()` return false in certain circumstances as the variable returned is not really empty?

Comment: Now that you mentioned, I noticed `isEmpty()` seems to not work with a single result. But the good old `empty()` was able to handle both, at least for me. I'm checking this in the view.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If the database query does not find any matching results, it returns `null`. Therefore...

```
$patient = Patient::where('name','=','Bob')->first();

if ( is_null($patient) ) {
  App::abort(404);
}
```

(Note: in your original question you forgot `->first()` (or `->get()`) in your query. Don't forget that or else you will get an Eloquent object instead of a result.)

Answer (score 10):

use this:

```
$patient = Patient::where('name', '=', 'Bob')->firstOrFail();
```

it will return Eulqouent model on success or throw ModelNotFoundException upon failure.

Comment: The docs say to listen for the ModelNotFoundException with `App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{return Response::make('Not Found', 404);});` but it doesn't say where to put that code. Does it just come straight after the Eloquent query?

Comment: You can add that code in start/global.php or bootstrap/start.php.

Comment: Isn't that a little generic? What happens if you need to handle one missing model differently than other missing models? Maybe have you have Patient, Doctors, Nurses, Hospital models. You handle them all the same way?? Checking if the result `is_null` in the controller is a much better solution imo because you can handle each situation differently.

Comment: +1 for elegance but it does seem a little too generic.

Comment: You don't have to use listeners of course, simply wrap it in your controller in try/catch block and handle it in place. nothing too fancy :)

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old, but this came up as the 2nd google hit on a search, so . . . for cases where you are not expecting one record or cannot use `->firstOrFail()` (my use case is an async typeahead api that returns up to 10 results) the only thing that worked for me was count():

```
$patient = Patient::where('name', '=', 'Bob')->get(); //you could have more than one bob
if (!count($patient)) {
    return 'No records found';
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$patient = Patient::where('name','Bob')->get();

if ( $patient->isEmpty() ) {
  return response(['error' => 'Record not found'], 404);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like `Patient::where('name', '=', 'Bob')->exists()` may work. It will return a boolean.

Comment: If null is returned, then you will get an error when trying to call exists() on a non-existent object. This one won't work.

Comment: @Dan it actually works for me, because `first()` method at least in Laravel 5.5 does not return `NULL'!
Weired because in API docs it mentions that this method can return a null !!

Comment: ->exists() is a function of the query builder class, $patient is a collection.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `empty()` from native php will solve everything, if object null it will return true, if laravel's `collection` from query builder is empty (but initialized) it will return true too.

```
$contributor = Contributor::whereVendor('web')->first();
if(empty($contributor)){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `findOrFail($id)` in case of you are passing `id` parameter to fetch a single record

I ended up on this while seeking solution of `::find($id)->firstOrFail` syntax which is error-full.

```
$patient = Patient::findOrFail($id);
```